# error when adding existing project in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am configuring a new computer for programming, and have this strange problem.

In my solution I have currently 2 projects, and I want to add a third.
This is the same as on my current development computer.
So I do `right mouse` on the solution and choose `add existing project` and then I browse to the project file.
Now I get this error

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
>   --------------------------- The project file 'C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj'
>   has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer.

The project I am trying to add is located at `C:\Development\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls`

So why do I get this error ?

I have searched the whole folder `development` using `NotePad++` for the string `C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj` but could not find any file having that string.

How to tell VS to not go searching in that folder when adding the project ?

I should note that on the current computer the project is under source control using TFS. I already added the connection for TFS on the new computer and it seems to be working.
On the current computer the project is on EXACT the same location.

**EDIT**
To clarify, as requested in comments.
The project I am adding is located at
`C:\Development\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj`

But when adding it to the solution, VS is looking for this project
`C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj`

So I searched if there is a file somewhere on my disk that has the text `C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj` in it, but could not find any

So why does VS looks for my project there ? How can I make VS forget this folder ?

Comment: The whole middle section is kind of confusing; can you re-word it a give a little more clarity? The error message says it can't find the .csproj file at `C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj`. Then you say that it's located at `C:\Development\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls`. Is the third `gttDXControls` in this string the .csproj file or the directory? 

Because then you proceed to say that you can't find `C:\Development\Palm\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls\gttDXControls.csproj`. Which would make sense given the error...

Comment: @Chris I have made an edit in my question. I hope this makes it more clear